# Using PowerShell to query Active Directory and add data to new column of existing csv

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory, export-to-csv

I have a CSV with hundreds of usernames listed on it. In PowerShell I would like to run `Get-ADUser` and output their `DisplayName` in the adjacent cell. I also want to keep all the other information within the correct rows, and make sure if any usernames are not found in AD, that the output doesn't write the following `DisplayName` out of order. Can someone help me figure this out? I'm relatively new to PowerShell, and very new to using it to modify Excel.

For confidentiality, lets say my spreadsheet looks like this:

[image: Users]

This is what I have so far...

```
$userlist = Get-Content $home\Desktop\names.csv

ForEach ($user in $userlist) {
    Get-ADUser $user -Properties DisplayName | 
          Select-Object Name,DisplayName |
          Export-CSV $home\Desktop\new_names.csv -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Comment: please, read the instructions on how to format code. [*grin*] the page you used to create your question has a link to the instructions.

Comment: also, PLEASE, do not post pics of code/data/errors. WHY? because you force others to squint to see your text OR to type in the text before they can use it to test the situation. you already have it as text ... so why make it needlessly difficult to help you?

Comment: Why is the 'Last Logon' column in the given image holding the name of the users ?!

Comment: You need to have something in your csv with which you can uniquely identify each user. This can be the `SamAccountName`, `DistinguishedName`, `EmailAddress` and so on. All you show is a column `Last Logon` where it seems you have user first name and lastname combined with a dot. Is that the SamAccountName in your environment, or part of the emailaddress or UserPrincipalName or what?

Comment: Last Logon represents the last user to logon to a system that needs "attention". It is the SamAccountName of the last user to login to the system. I have that list as output from another program which is unable to give me all the information I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Import-CSV $home\Desktop\names.csv |
    ForEach-Object {
      $samAccountname = ""
      $displayname = ""
      $samAccountname = $_."last logon"
      $machinename = $_.'machine name'
      $displayname = (get-aduser $samaccountname -Properties displayname).displayname
      $ou = $_.OU
      [pscustomobject]@{
            machineName=$machinename
            displayname=$displayname 
            OU=$ou 
            samAccountname=$samAccountname 
        }
    } |
    select samAccountname ,machineName,displayname,ou |
    Export-CSV new_names.csv -Append -NoTypeInformation
```

In the above I am making the assumption that "Last Logon" in your spreadsheet is each user's `samaccountname`. Steps taken:

- Import the original csv
- On each loop we assign each value from each row to a variable
- For our new column "displayname" we use the `get-aduser` cmdlet along with the samaccountname info from our csv
- Create a `psobject` to hold this information from the variables
- We then use `Select-Object` to select the order of the spreadsheet headers prior to passing it to `export-csv` to produce our updated csv

Comment: This is the closest to working as I intended. The only issue is that some of the samAccountNames are for local-logins and not domain logins. When the get-aduser command fails to find the local logins in AD [ADIdentityNotFoundException], it is writing the preveous user's samAccountName in the current object's "last login"(samAccountName) cell.

Comment: @Jarad I have updated the code to reset the samaccountname `$samaccountname = ""`to prevent the previous users details being held

Comment: It works perfectly now, thank you so much! I understand the code pretty well, but I will conduct some research so I can better understand how to use "pscustomobject".  Bravo!

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below script if you have the samaccountname of the user. 
If you have the distinguishedname just comment out samaccountname portions and uncomment distinguishedname portions.

```
$userlist = Import-Csv "$home\Desktop\names.csv"

ForEach ($user in $userlist) {

    $SamID_User = $user.SamAccountName
    # $DN_User = $user.DistinguishedName
    $OU_User = $user.OU

    #A Search by SamAccountName
    $result = Get-ADUser -Filter { samaccountname -eq $SamID_User } -SearchBase $OU_User  | # DisplayName property is returned by default by Get-ADUser and hence doesn't require explicit mention
          Select-Object Name,DisplayName

    $result | Export-CSV "$home\Desktop\new_names.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Append # Added -Append switch; works on PS v3.0 and later; with PS v2.0 -Append switch is not available with Export-Csv; With PS v2.0 you can use Out-File instead

    #B Search by DistinguishedName
    <#
    $result = Get-ADUser -Filter { DistinguishedName -eq $DN_User } -SearchBase $OU_User | 
          Select-Object Name,DisplayName
    $result | Export-CSV "$home\Desktop\new_names.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Append
    #>

}
```

Hope this helps.